# Can I see the list of people I've invited to Facebook?

Tags: facebook

A friend of mine relayed me a mail that said I invited him to Facebook, which I'm pretty sure I didn't do. Now, I'm worried that there are other people I've unexpectedly invited to join Facebook.

Is there a way for me to see the list of people I've invited to Facebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the list of people you have invited to join Facebook in your **[Invite History](https://www.facebook.com/invite_history.php)**.

While there, you can delete any pending invites that you might have accidentally sent or no longer want.

Comment: How do you navigate to your "Invite History" without coming to this answer and clicking the link every time? :)

Comment: Don't know. There used to be a path to it, but I think it has been last since the profile redesign.

Comment: You can get to it by clicking "Find Friends" in the left sidebar, then click on the text "manage imported contacts" near the top.